# VBA Save ONLY VISIBLE Sheet as Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I was working with the following VBA (attached below). It works great, and what I like the most is that it is Path/Name independent. 
I am now trying to save multiple reports which are based on some HiddenSheets (very hidden), which I don't want to include. The problem with this Macro is that it creates individual Worksheets for every sheet, including the invisible sheets. 
Is there a chance to have the whole same concept of creating a folder with the same workbook name but only include the visible sheets?
If so, please let me know. I have been trying to tweak this code so much, and it either includes only one sheet or all of them (not the visible only)
Thanks!

```
Sub SaveShtsAsBook()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet, SheetName$, MyFilePath$, N&
    MyFilePath$ = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
    Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
         '      End With
        On Error Resume Next '<< a folder exists
        MkDir MyFilePath '<< create a folder
        For N = 1 To Sheets.Count
            Sheets(N).Activate
            SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
            Cells.Copy
            Workbooks.Add (xlWBATWorksheet)
            With ActiveWorkbook
                With .ActiveSheet
                    .Paste
                    .Name = SheetName
                    [A1].Select
                End With
                 'save book in this folder
                .SaveAs Filename:=MyFilePath _
                & "\" & SheetName & ".xlsx"
                .Close SaveChanges:=True
            End With
            .CutCopyMode = False
        Next
    End With
    Sheet1.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a hidden worksheet can be xlSheetHidden (0) or xlSheetVeryHidden (2), if it is visible it can only be xlSheetVisible (-1). You can check the [Worksheet.Visible property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.visible) and determine whether you want to proceed or not.

As a shortcut, if you copy a worksheet without providing a destination then you create a new copy of the original workbook with a single worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveShtsAsBook()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet, MyFilePath As String, w As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    On Error Resume Next '<< a folder exists

    'define the workbook
    With ThisWorkbook

        MyFilePath = Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".") - 1)
        MkDir MyFilePath '<< create a folder

        For w = 1 To .Worksheets.Count

            'check if worksheet is visible
            If .Worksheets(w).Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

                .Worksheets(w).Copy   'create new active workbook with copy of worksheet

                With ActiveWorkbook
                    .Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "A").Select
                     'save book in this folder. Use FileFormat argument instead of adding .XLSX
                    .SaveAs Filename:=MyFilePath & "\" & .Worksheets(1).Name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                    'close saving changes
                    .Close SaveChanges:=True
                End With

            End If

        Next w

    End With

    Sheet1.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the sheets where `Worksheets("Sheet1").visible = False`

Comment: The sheets (I want to exclude are already hidden) yet the macro above would still create individual workbooks (including Hidden/VeryHidden sheets)